# Date-wise and bucket capacity-wise serial number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, partition

I couldn't give an appropriate title to my problem. Let me explain it through example.

Suppose I have the following table

**INPUT**

[image]

**What I want**

- First, I want to group the transactions by date (dd-MM-yyyy)
- Then I want to create a chunk/bucket of at most 2 items. Thus I want to assign a sub_batch_ref_id to each chunk/bucket of 2 items. In each chunk/bucket transactions must belong to exactly one date.
- Convention of SUB_BATCH_REF_ID is BATCH_REF{global serial number of chunk/bucket}
- A chunk or bucket can contain at most 2 items of the same date

I understand that this can be achieved through any high-level programming language (except data-oriented language like SQL) quite easily but I don't have such provision. The solution can be shaped into the following pseudocode for better understanding:

**Pseudocode**

```
//I have the following map (assumed)
Map<Date, List<Transaction>> dateWiseTransactions;
BUCKET_CAPACITY = 2
GLOBAL_SERIAL = 0
for each entry in dateWiseTransactions
LOOP
    GLOBAL_SERIAL = GLOBAL_SERIAL + 1;
    for each transaction in entry.value i.e. List<Transaction>
    LOOP
        if loopIndex > BUCKET_CAPACITY //loopIndex starts from 1
            GLOBAL_SERIAL = GLOBAL_SERIAL + 1
        end if;
        transaction.SUB_BATCH_REF_ID = CONCAT(transaction.BATCH_REF, GLOBAL_SERIAL)
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

[image]

**What I tried**

I tried to partition the transaction data by date first then assigned a row number but I couldn't come to a solution.

```
SELECT 
T.*,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY TRUNC(INSERT_DATE) ORDER BY TRANSACTION_ID) rn
FROM TRANSACTION T
WHERE BATCH_REF='XYZ'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b984/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an optimal solution.  Your actual problem is a rather complex graph problem -- because you want transactions only to be used once over all the dates.

One solution is to assign a "working" date to the transaction.  The following does this randomly:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY TRUNC(INSERT_DATE) ORDER BY TRANSACTION_ID) AS rn
      FROM (SELECT T.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BATCH_REF, TRANSACTION_ID ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM) as seqnum
            FROM TRANSACTION T
            ) T
      WHERE BATCH_REF = 'XYZ' AND 
            SEQNUM = 1
     ) T
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the sample input and expected output since there were wrong (same) transaction IDs for the last 4 entries. Can you please suggest if there's an optimal solution to this problem even if it can be achieved through a stored procedure or multiple SQLS.